# Could not init /home/biswajeet/.jenkins/workspace

Tags: git, jenkins

my question is about while try to complie a code in jenkins i am getting below error.

Could not init /home/biswajeet/.jenkins/workspace

Comment: Started by user biswajeetbehera
Building in workspace /home/biswajeet/.jenkins/workspace/tomcat2
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/biswajeetbehera/tomcat2.git
 >  init /home/biswajeet/.jenkins/workspace/tomcat2 # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/biswajeet/.jenkins/workspace/tomcat2
 at o

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me ??

Comment: Please read more on how to ask good questions on stackoverflow.  You are violating most of the written and unwritten rules, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if git is installed on your machine by using "where git" on the CMD line in Windows or "which git" in Linux.

If that works, make sure Jenkins is configured correctly under Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Git > Path to Git (or something similar).

Comment: after giving which git i got - /usr/bin/git

Comment: And did you follow the next step to make sure Jenkins was configured correctly?

Comment: but i am unable to see git under configure system

Comment: yes i have installed jenkins in my ubantu machine successfully

Comment: I'm not asking if you've installed Jenkins.  I'm asking if it was configured correctly.  You need to make sure Jenkins knows where git is installed to so it can use it correctly.  I think you need to read a tutorial on how to set up Jenkins.

Comment: can u suggest any url for it

Comment: am getting this error now "Couldn’t find any executable in usr/share/maven Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE"